# WebAPI JSON Serialize Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core-webapi

In my WebAPI, I'm using EF. I'm currently getting my data out using a LINQ statement.

My LINQ is:

```
var output = _context.CarMakes
.Select(x => new 
{
   id= x.CarId,
   make = x.CarMake,
   year = x.Year,
   status = x.Status 
});
```

my data is returned as:

```
[
     { 
        "id": 1,
        "make": "Ford",
         "year" : 2020,
        "model" : "Focus"
     },
     {
        "id" : 2,
        "make" :"Ford",
        "year" : 1994,
        "model" : "F-150"
     },
     {
       "id" : 3,
       "make" : "Chevy",
       "year" : 2022,
       "model" : "Silverado"
  
     }
   ]
```

How can I get it returned so it's grouped so  I can use it in a TreeView navigation menu such as: What changes should I make to the .NET code?

```
   Ford:
      2020
        Focus
       1994
         F-150
   Chevy
       2022
         Silverado
```

Comment: `make` is twice in your JSON.

Answer (score 2):

you need to use group by to get the result needed, here is an example  :

```
var result = _context.CarMakes.GroupBy(x => x.make)
    .Select(g => new {
        Make = g.Key,
        Models = g.GroupBy(x => x.year)
            .Select(y => new {
                Year = y.Key,
                Name = y.Select(z => z.model)
            })
    });
```

Comment: This is what I'm looking for, thanks, I need to add the ID field to this as well so when the user clicks on the mdoel, It'll take them to the details for that model, Is there a way to add the ID field for the model and still have  it grouped as such?

Answer (score 0):

You have to perform group by on `make` and `year` fields and then select all the cars that come under those grouping. Then in the front end, you can use this returned data to make a nested tree view.

```
var output = _context.CarMakes
    .Select(x => new
    {
        id = x.CarId,
        make = x.CarMake,
        year = x.Year,
        status = x.Status
    })
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.make, x.year })
    .Select(g => new
    {
        make = g.Key.make,
        year = g.Key.year,
        cars = g.Select(x => new { id = x.id, status = x.status })
    });
```